# Fast emacs executable with dump-emacs?

Tags: emacs

I came across this [article](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DumpingEmacs)
about speeding up the emacs startup.

I wanted to try it, but I get a segfault.
Has anyone managed to do this for recent emacs versions?

Here's the makefile I'm using:

```
emacs=/usr/local/bin/emacs
fast-emacs:  /usr/local/bin/emacs ~/.emacs
    $(emacs) -Q --batch -l "~/.emacs" \
    --execute "(dump-emacs \"fast-emacs\" \"$(emacs)\")"
```

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/2rietp/dumpemacs_truly_speeds_up_emacs_startup/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This trick stopped working sometime after emacs21, and dump-emacs now only works with the bootstrap `temacs` to turn it into a full-blown emacs.  When emacs has been dumped once, it can't be dumped again.

The `site-init.el` trick referenced on the wiki *might* do the trick, but I suspect you're going to run into serious stability problems once you start including a bunch of packages in the image.  All in all, really not worth it.

Answer (score 0):

An another solution is posted on Reddit in the case if the linked page above is not working or dead, and the suggested solution should be faster too (time startup: 0.00 seconds).

http://www.reddit.com/r/emacs/comments/2rietp/dumpemacs_truly_speeds_up_emacs_startup/

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged on SO. Please add the relevant content directly to your answer instead.